# print some text every Nth line in bash

Tags: bash

How to throttle the output of some command to print three lines, wait and print something and print next three lines and keep doing it. Note that sometime this tool prints lot of data together or sometimes it prints very slowly(its kind of tail command). I need to do this using pure bash, cannot use awk.

```
./sometool
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
```

expected result:

```
./sometool| <some pure bash loginc/no awk>
line1
line2
line3
#some randon text
line4
line5
line6
#some randon text
line7
line8
line9
#some randon text
line10
...
```

did it with awk but needed a bash approch:

```
./sometool |awk 'NR%3==0{$0= $0 RS"#some randon text"}1'
line1
line2
line3
#some randon text
line4
line5
line6
#some randon text
line7
line8
line9
#some randon text
line10
```

Comment: Are you not sure how to get started? Use a `while read` loop to process input line by line. Here's the external [BashFaq #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: not sure how to implement `NR%3==0` check in bash as I do not know how  while loop keep track of line number specially if the input is having unknown number of lines and is continuous stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ seq 10 | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; if [[ $((++c%3)) -eq 0 ]]; then echo "some random text"; fi; done

1
2
3
some random text
4
5
6
some random text
7
8
9
some random text
10
```

create a line counter modulo 3 and do the same logic as in `awk`.  I think this can be simplified a bit.

Comment: or without counter: `seq 10 | while read -r l && echo "$l" && read -r l && echo "$l" && read -r l && echo "$l"; do echo "some random text"; done`

Comment: or working better with input like `-e` and `*` while being slightly shorter:  `seq 10 | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; ((++c%3)) || echo "some random text"; done`

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
some process that generates output | while 
    IFS= read -r first
    IFS= read -r second
    IFS= read -r third
do
    echo "$first"
    echo "$second"
    echo "$third"
    echo "some random text"
done
```

Obviously inflexible for values of N != 3